# How to make a css table reponsive?

Tags: html, css

All the boxes are lined up horizontally side by side in one line. How can I make this responsive when I shrink the browser so that each box will slide down vertically?

Also how do I stop the tables cell from shrinking when resizing, I tried using table-layout: fixed, but it does not work.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">
   <img src="image.gif">
  </div>
   <div class="box">
   <img src="image.gif">
  </div>
   <div class="box">
   <img src="image.gif">
  </div>
   <div class="box">
   <img src="image.gif">
  </div>
   <div class="box">
   <img src="image.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
}

.container {
display:table;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}

.box {
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}

img {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: If you want a table, then use the `<table>` tab that's what it is for. Also its semantic. It automatically shrinks to fit in the window as best it can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "min-height: xx%" and "max-height: xx%".
When you're working with responsive layouts consider using XX% instead XXpx.